# How do I import my VPS SSL certificate into my jetty keystore using keytools?

Tags: java, ssl, https, embedded-jetty, b4j

I have written a webapp in B4J, which is a Basic language IDE that compiles the app to an executable java jar. My webapp works fine on http but I now need to embed it into a WordPress page, which I do using an iframe plugin for WordPress.

The WordPress site runs on http**s** so I therefore need to have my webapp run on https. I've searched the B4J forum and successfully converted the webapp so that the embedded jetty server starts up and connects on https but I am now in the world of SSL, which I have never had to deal with before.

I've followed various howto's and tutorials and successfully created a self-signed SSL cert using 'keytool' and that has allowed me to test and prove that my webapp is running under https. However the time has come for me upgrade the SSL cert to 'proper' certification so that the webapp can run without the browser warnings caused by the self-signed cert.

So this is where my SSL ability becomes super-thin...
My VPS host is HostGator (HG) and the VPS plan comes with a free SSL cert that is periodically renewed. The HG cert covers the domain that both the WordPress site and the webapp will run on. I have asked HG Support whether their free cert would cover my webppp and they seem to think that it would but I need to make it available to the webapp when the java jar starts up the Jetty server.
To that end I would like to try and import the HG cert into my Jetty keystore file and see it it will work. My problem is that I am unsure about:

- Where the HG SSL cert is or what it looks like; and
- How to actually import the HG SSL Cert into my Jetty keystore

I have read various threads both on B4J forum and StackOverflow but I'm not confident at this point that I know what I'm doing. I would greatly appreciate any assistance given and can supply the following information to help.

- I can view the HG SSL certs on the HG VPS WHM panel. It covers the domain I am using.
- I created my Jetty keystore (self-signed) using 'keytool'
- The jetty keystore (called jetty.keystore) is stored in the root directory of the webapp.
- The jetty.keystore has storetype PKCS12, which the process prompted me to do when I created it.

Having search some Linux forums I am pretty sure that the HG SSL cert is in a file located in:

- /etc/pki/tls/certs
- in that directory are links to ca-bundle.crt and ca-bundle.trust.crt; and
- a file called *mydomain.com*.**crt**

So...my question is:

- is *mydomain.com*.**crt** likely to be the HG VPS free domain SSL cert?
- If so, how do I go about importing that cert into my jetty.keystore file?

Comment: Yes, `mydomain.com.crt` is very likely to be your SSL site certificate, and you can import it via `keytool -import`, but first you will need to locate your private key, which will be somewhere near the certificate, and import that, probably by converting it to a PKCS#12 keystore with the OpenSSL tool. Have a good look at the Tomcat SSL documents, which cover all this, even if you aren't using Tomcat. You need to use the same keystore alias for both the private key and the certificate, and you need the private key in there first.

Comment: Thanks for the tip MoL, greatly appreciated... By way of clarification... Is the 'private key' another file? If so, can you explain what it would look like in terms of it's name?

Comment: There is a 'cert.pem' file in the /etc/pki/tls directory, which looks like it is a link to /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/pem/tls-ca-bundle.pem
Would that be the private key?

Comment: With all that said...if I look into the VPS WHM panel... I can see in the SSL Storage Manager a UI view of **Website SSL/TLS Resources**, that shows 3 certificates and a private key that look like:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGrjCCBZagAwIBAgIRAK0pPkzRd9Y50p2/6/............

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEpAIBAAKCAQEAv9rCj6S2cVQv8gtbU8......

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIF8TCCA9mgAwIBAgIRAPAd.....

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFfjCCBGagAwIBAgIQZ97...

Am I able to cut and paste the contents of these into a file and then import them into my jetty keystore via keytools?

Comment: What part of this isn't covered by the Tomcat documentation?

Comment: Tip, don't think of this as a "Jetty Keystore", you want a "Java Keystore".  Your goal is a "Java Keystore" in the PKCS12 storage format.

Comment: Unless I'm reading the wrong Tomcat documentation...it only tells me the commands to use, which I get. What I don't understand is what I am importing.
I don't know if the previously mentioned crt and pem files are the right ones. The content doesn't seem to match content shown in the WHM panel.
Hence...I'm confident that the certs/key shown in WHM are what I'm looking for but they only show the content not where the actual file is. As such I would like to know if I can just cut&paste the cert/key content into some files and import those?

Comment: Only you can know whether you've got the right files. You've been told what you need. I don't understand what you're expecting to learn here.

Comment: I can only say in response that, "I don't know what I don't know". In the end I have just got it working but the WHM cert and PK were actually located in a different directory with weird names. After watching a heap of youtube vids and looking at other sites I created a keystore using keytools, emptied the contents, then used openssl to create a PKCS12 version of the cert and PK, and finally imported that into the keystore. I'm sad to say that I fluked it rather than worked it out. But at least I now know how to do it and it works... Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

- Using Developer tools in Chrome...View the SSL Certificate and Private Key for the domain.
- Locate both of these files on the VPS, which were under the domain owners account, not the root account.
- Make sure the cert and PK match the ones displayed in Chrome Developer Tools view.
- keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias jetty -keystore *jetty.keystore* -keysize 2048
- Enter the prompted answers.
- keytool -delete -alias jetty -storepass *keystore-password-value* -keystore *jetty.keystore*
- keytool -list -storepass *keystore-password-value* -keystore *jetty.keystore* (to check that the key store is empty)
- openssl pkcs12 -export -in */../../cert-directory/certificate-file.crt* -inkey */../../cert-directory/pk-file.key* -name host -out *outfile.p12*
- keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass *keystore-password-value* -destkeystore *jetty.keystore* -srckeystore *outfile.p12* -srcstoretype PKCS12

<sub>*Answer added on behalf of OP*</sub>